# Opencart передать переменную из одного контроллера в другой

Tags: php, opencart

я использую opencart 3.0.2 у меня есть категории которые хранятся в БД, мне нужно выводить их в шапке и в футере, сейчас я делаю 2 запроса в БД и не пойму каким образом мне их передать из шапки сайта в футер? Использовать глобальные переменные не хотелось бы, может уже есть реализация для этой цели?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в Opencart контролеры никак не могут взаимодействовать друг с другом.

На вашем бы месте я написал бы отдельный модуль. Возьмите уже готовый модуль и посмотрите как там реализовано. Уроков в сети по этой теме полно, но дам черновой вариант:

Создаём файл для модуля:
\catalog\controller\extension\module\customcategory.php

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionCustomcategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        /*

        тут будет вся логика вашего модуля

        */

        return 'что-нибудь';
    }
}
```

Также найдите как вынести в админку модуль (чтобы была возможность включать/выключать его).

После этого в контроллерах `header.php` и `footer.php` вы можете подгрузить модуль и вызывать нужные методы:

```
$customcategory = $this->load->controller('controller/extension/module/customcategory');
```

И уже из контроллеров можете передать в шаблон ваш результат.

Это грубый черновой вариант, чтобы дать понять как всё это можно сделать. План к действию дал, в интернете всё более подробно сможете найти, так как кода много, всё сюда не вмещу.